# Name of a dictionary is not defined accessing through console

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

In my routes.py I set a variable to the converted dictionary generated from SQLAlchemy tuples right after the form validation statement.

When typing `from routes import *`
`dict(Book.query.with_entities(Book.username, Book.choice).all())` in console i get the correct dictionary as wanted `{'user1': 'choice1', 'user2': 'choice2'}`

If I type the name of the variable ***dict_of_users*** assiged to this dictionary I get: *NameError: name 'dict_of_users' is not defined*

Why it does not recognise that variable since it is in the code?

The logic behind I want to achieve:

If the user select one choice from available in the list, that user and its choice are added as key and value in the dictionary, otherwise the dictionary is empty.

**My routes.py**:

```
@app.route("/booking", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def booking():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=5)
    form = BookingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        book = Book(username=current_user.username, choice=form.book.data)
        db.session.add(book)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your choice is registered', 'success')
    dict_of_users = dict(Book.query.with_entities(Book.username, Book.choice).all())
    return render_template('booking.html', title='Booking', form=form, dict_of_users=dict_of_users)
```

Comment: Is the dict of users variable a global variable?

Comment: no it is inside only this function booking()

Comment: @Glitch__ Thank you for clarifying this. If I want to access that variable inside the function  do I type `booking.dict_of_users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only inside of the function, you can't access it outside of the function. Since the variable is only defined in the function, you get the `NameError` message. A fix is to define the variable in the global scope.

EDIT:

As a response to your comment:

if you want to access the `dict_of_users` variable, declare it outside of the function. Then the variable will contain the value of it's latest use in the global scope, and thus accesible outside of the function.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
dict_of_users = None

@app.route("/booking", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def booking():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=5)
    form = BookingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        book = Book(username=current_user.username, choice=form.book.data)
        db.session.add(book)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your choice is registered', 'success')
    dict_of_users = dict(Book.query.with_entities(Book.username, Book.choice).all())
    return render_template('booking.html', title='Booking', form=form, dict_of_users=dict_of_users)
```

Comment: Hi @Glitch__ this still doesn't work having a global variable outside of the function. The dictionary returns empty even if it it with data.

Comment: Do you still get the NameError?

Comment: All good, I figured out, there was a typo from my side.

Comment: In that case, if my answer solved your question, can you accept my anwer? Then the question will be markted as solved.